# How to locate workflows on a tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, flow

How do you find other workflows on your tenant if the end users that are creating them do not share them with you?

Is this found in the Power Platform admin center?

Comment: Hi @David, does below answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

**From Admin Center**:

If you have administrator access on the given Power Platform environment, you can find all the flows created by all users from admin center.

Check this article for more information: [Manage Flows in the Admin Center and two new services](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-flow-resources-in-the-admin-center)

---

**Using Power Automate Management connector**:

You can also create a Power automate or Power apps and list all flows in a environment using [List Flows as Admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/flowmanagement/#list-flows-as-admin) action provided by "Power Automate Management" connector.

---

**Using PowerShell**:

You can also use [Get-AdminFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/get-adminflow?) command in PowerShell to get the flows in your environment.